# Select 100 rows from data table using query

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatable

I am using jQuery DataTable. I have 100 rows in data table and check box in table rows. I wants to checked top 30 rows on button click. How can I do that?

Comment: what have you done so far...plz share

Comment: Fiddle will be nice to solve.

Comment: Please share your code and be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK you can use the slice method which allows you to concentrate on a section of data (in this case 30 items). From here we can use the each method which allows us to iterate over the sliced collection and check the inputs.

```
$(#table tr).slice(0,29).each(function(index, value){

   $(value).child('input:checkbox:first').prop('checked', true);

});
```

If you're using Jquery 1.5 or below you will need to use the attr to check the check box. I am unable to test this code myself but it should give you a good idea of what is required.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
function Check(tableid){
    var checkboxes = $(tableid + ' checkbox')
    for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++){
      if(i < checkboxes.length){
        $(checkboxes[i])addAttr("checked", "checked");
      }
    }
}

<button onclick="check('#mytable')"></button>
```

Comment: is there any way to do using Data table?

Comment: Thanks for work arround solution.